Solve assertion "Balloc succeeded" failed: file "/build/gnu-tools-for-stm32_10.3-2021.10.202111-1100/src/newlib/newlib/libc/stdlib/mprec.c", line 778
I was working on a project with STM32L452RET6 using baremetal programming. I use Uart1, Uart2, I2C, Timer6, Timer2, RTC and GPIOs for my project. Uart2, RTC and Timer 6 works in interrupt with priority 1,0,2 respectively. Uart1 is remapped with printf statement for debugging purpose. Randomly facing "assertion "Balloc succeeded" failed: file "/build/gnu-tools-for-stm32_10.3-2021.10.20211105-1100/src/newlib/newlib/libc/stdlib/mprec.c", line 778" in the runtime and code gets stuck. Not able to identify the issue.
Tried to find the file mentioned in the error but not found in the repository. Since its getting in random not able to find any more details.
Please help with a solution.
Thanks,
Suhaib Saiyde.
